# Exception from QTextEdit textChanged signal

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qtextedit

I'm using Python3 and PyQt5 to create an application containing form elements such as `QLineEdit` and `QTextEdit`.

I collect data from a `QLineEdit` as follows (this is working properly):

```
    self.rolAdi = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
    self.rolAdi.setObjectName("rolAdi")

    self.rolAdi.textChanged.connect(self.textSonDurum)

def textSonDurum(self, s):
    print("Text changed...>>> "+s)
```

However, the same method using a `QTextEdit` control doesn't work - the program stops whenever I change the content of the control:

```
   self.IP = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
   self.IP.setObjectName("IP")

   self.IP.textChanged.connect(self.textSonDurum)

def textSonDurum(self, s):
    print("Text changed...>>> "+s)
```

I researched about this problem and I found a suggestion involving using the disconnect function, but  cannot find it in PyQt5.

```
self.IP.textChanged.disconnect()
```

**Output Error**:

```
TypeError: disconnect() failed between 'textChanged' and all its connections
```

(The full code is very long to paste it here but let me know if you need any other part).

Comment: When `textChanged` signal (`QTextEdit`) is raised  the new text (`s` argument) isn't passed to slot: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged vs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QTextEdit` [textChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged) has a different signature to the `QLineEdit` [textChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged), in that it doesn't pass the text that was changed. This is because `QTextEdit` supports rich-text (i.e. html) as well as plain-text, so you need to explicitly request the content-type you want:

```
   self.IP.textChanged.connect(self.textSonDurum)

def textSonDurum(self):
    print("Text changed...>>> " + self.IP.toPlainText())
```